# Media Player behaves strangely, android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my app, I have background music and some voices to play. I want to music pause when voice is playing, and when voice finishes, I have to restart the music. So following case pauses the background music and start the voice. Then I have onVoiceFinish() method which checks whether voice finished.

```
case "%voice_1": {
            activity.getMusic().pause();
            MediaPlayer music = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.intro);
            onVoiceFinish(music);
            music.start();
            break;
        }
```

My onVoiceFinish() is here:

```
public void onVoiceFinish(final MediaPlayer voice){
    voice.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            activity.getMusic().start();
            voice.release();
        }

    });
}
```

So my problem is sometimes background music does not restart and voice stops before it finishes. Did I use setOnCompletion() method correctly?

Comment: My guess is that `activity` is getting things messy. Maybe it is destroyed sometimes or get paused or stopped.

Comment: I found I guess, it somehow destroys the media player. I think it was because I started the voice in a local method. So I  wrote global instance of "MediaPlayer voice". And now it works.